# How to Identify steps in ASP.NET Wizard control?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET Wizard Control. I have 11 Slides ( IN GIF) format for which I used Image Control in each Wizard step.  Now I added five seconds delay in each step's NEXT button using JQuery and and I did it and it is working fine.

My Problem is I am assigning Java Script in the code behind to the each NEXT button on each step Now, the issue is NEXT Button is rendered as three different name in Wizard control  i.e (StartNextButton) then (StepNextButton) and in last step it is rendered as (FinishButton)

Now how can make my Jquery function generic enough to be used with all the NEXT buttons?   OR is there any way in code behind  I can identity on which step (Slide) so i can assign Jquery function accordingly?

For First Step:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "disabled", JsTimerFunction("Wizard1_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton"), true);
```

This is the way I assign Jquery function for every step in Wizard Control except the first and the last..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "disabled", JsTimerFunction("Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton"), true);
```

For Last Button

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "disabled", JsTimerFunction("Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishButton"), true);
```

This is my server side code to generate the Jquery string

```
     private string JsTimerFunction(string ctrlID){

        var str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine();
        str.AppendLine(" $( document ).ready(function() {");
        str.AppendLine("var button = $(\"#" + ctrlID + "\");" );
        str.AppendLine("var oldValue = $(\"#" + ctrlID + "\").value;");
        str.AppendLine("button.attr('disabled', true);");
        str.AppendLine("button.value = 'Wait 5 sec';");
        str.AppendLine();
        str.AppendLine("setTimeout(function () {");
        str.AppendLine("button.value = oldValue;");
        str.AppendLine("button.removeAttr('disabled');");
        str.AppendLine(" }, 5000)");
        str.AppendLine();
        str.AppendLine(" });");

        return str.ToString();
    }
```

And this is my Wizard Control Listing in ASP.NET page:

```
 <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" DisplaySideBar="False" Height="357px" Width="623px" FinishPreviousButtonText="سابق" StepNextButtonText="التالى" StepPreviousButtonText="سابق" FinishCompleteButtonText="اذهب الى اختبار" StartNextButtonText="التالى" OnActiveStepChanged="Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged" OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">
        <FinishNavigationTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveComplete" Text="اذهب الى اختبار" />
            <asp:Button ID="FinishPreviousButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Text="سابق" />
        </FinishNavigationTemplate>
        <NavigationStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <StepNextButtonStyle BorderStyle="None" />
        <StartNavigationTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="التالى" />
        </StartNavigationTemplate>
        <StepNavigationTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server"  EnableTheming="True" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="التالى" />
            <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" EnableTheming="True" Text="سابق" />
        </StepNavigationTemplate>
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 1">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 2">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/2.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
             <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 3">
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/3.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
             <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 4">
                <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/4.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
             <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 5">
                <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/5.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
             <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 6">
                <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/6.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
             <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 7">
                <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/7.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
             <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 8">
                <asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/8.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
             <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 9">
                <asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/9.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 10">
                <asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/10.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Step 11">
                <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/11.png" Width="614px" />
            </asp:WizardStep>

        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

Now how can make my Jquery function generic enough to be used with all the NEXT buttons in the wizard control OR is there any way in code behind I can identity on which step (Slide) so i can assign Jquery function accordingly?

Can anyone Help me out?

Comment: Yes, you can do all this just using a simple single client-side script without requiring hard-wired IDs. Forget injecting hard-wired Javascript/jQuery via code-behind. Just include a script file and solve the problem client-side with jQuery. If you supply the output HTML (e.g. as saved from the browser), I will mock up an example.

Comment: You can also make your "Next" button generic and take it out of the wizard control. Then, you can simply assign java script only once for that one "Next" button. I have done something like this a while ago and it's simple enough.